# How do I plot sentiment polarity chart using sentiment score?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, machine-learning, data-science, sentiment-analysis

I have been able to do the sentiment analysis with the sentiment score. But i am having problem plotting it as a chart.

Here is code on the sentiment score, but i also want to include a chart.

```
def senti_sc(x):
    if x is not None:
       return TextBlob(x).sentiment

dataframe_3["Sentiment_score"]= dataframe_3["extracted_emojis"].apply(senti_sc)
print(dataframe_3.loc[0:19,['extracted_emojis','Sentiment_score']])
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to know what you would like to plot, but here is an aexample:

```
import pandas as pd
from textblob import TextBlob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    'text': ['I love this!', 'This is terrible.', 'I am neutral.'],
    'Sentiment_score': [TextBlob('I love this!').sentiment.polarity,
                        TextBlob('This is terrible.').sentiment.polarity,
                        TextBlob('I am neutral.').sentiment.polarity]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create bar chart
plt.bar(df['text'], df['Sentiment_score'])
plt.title('Sentiment Analysis')
plt.xlabel('Text')
plt.ylabel('Sentiment Score')
plt.show()
```

which gives

[image]

Another is

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from textblob import TextBlob

data = {
    'text': ['I love this!', 'This is terrible.', 'I am neutral.'],
    'sentiment_score': [TextBlob('I love this!').sentiment.polarity,
                        TextBlob('This is terrible.').sentiment.polarity,
                        TextBlob('I am neutral.').sentiment.polarity]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

pos = (df['sentiment_score'] > 0).sum()
neg = (df['sentiment_score'] < 0).sum()
neu = (df['sentiment_score'] == 0).sum()

plt.pie([pos, neg, neu], labels=['Positive', 'Negative', 'Neutral'], autopct='%1.1f%%')
plt.title('Sentiment Analysis')
plt.show()
```

[image]
and yet another one

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

text = "I love this product. It is amazing! The customer service is excellent."

wordcloud = WordCloud(width=800, height=800, background_color='white').generate(text)
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]